# Clojure - Slice a 2D vector vectically

Tags: arrays, clojure, slice

I have a 2D vector that looks like this

```
 (["2011-01-01" "2011" "01" "01"]
 ["1869-01-01" "1869" "01" "01"]
 ["1922-01-01" "1922" "01" "01"]
 ["1905-01-01" "1905" "01" "01"])
```

I want to have just a vector of just the second column so it will be like this

```
("2011" "1869" "1922" "1905")
```

What is the best way to do this in Clojure?

Comment: What have you tried? How has it failed? Please add the code and the error message you got, so we can improve on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to always consult [the Clojure CheatSheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet) for questions like this.

For something this simple, just use `mapv` (or `map`) and the `second` function:

```
(def data [["2011-01-01" "2011" "01" "01"]
           ["1869-01-01" "1869" "01" "01"]
           ["1922-01-01" "1922" "01" "01"]
           ["1905-01-01" "1905" "01" "01"]])

(mapv second data) => ["2011" "1869" "1922" "1905"]
```

I prefer `mapv` since it gives the result as a vector (non-lazy) which is easier to cut & paste w/o needing quotes.

---

If you have more complicated needs, you may wish to review [the `tupelo.array` library](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.184/api/tupelo.array).  Your data is already in the form of a Clojure 2-D array (vector of vectors), so you can just use the `col-get` function:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.array :as ta]))

(def data ...)

; Note zero-based indexing
(ta/col-get data 1) => ["2011" "1869" "1922" "1905"]
```

The library includes many other functions for input/output, get/set values, flip arrays up/down or left/right, rotation, adding/deleting rows & cols, etc.  There is also [a version that works with mutable arrays](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.184/api/tupelo.array.mutable) (Java native object arrays) instead of Clojure immutable data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Possible answers

A. `(reduce  (fn [| [_ - ]] (conj | -)) [] data)`

B. `(map (fn [[_ - ]] -) data)`

C. `(map second data)`

Comment: I really don't think giving the functions obscure parameter names helps anything here. `_`, ok, but a bar and dash?

Comment: @Carcigenicate could not agree more! My attempt at code golf. Could not find a simpler, shorter, clearer solution than (map second data) or (mapv second data)

Comment: I disagree with the entire concept of code golf.  If you want to make something obscure & short, use `gzip`.  Otherwise, please use real names that make the code as obvious as possible.

Comment: @KobbyPemson , in fact  `(map #(% 1)data)` is one (space) char shorter than `(map second data)`.. )) but right: golfing is a terrible thing..

Comment: Brevity isn't necessary; and especially not in an answer that otherwise has no explanation. You need description either by writing self explanatory code and/or describing the code in the answer.

Comment: @leetwinski I didn't know you could use vectors as functions like  maps and sets. It unfortunately throws an IOOB exception when you access non existent positions. Definitely avoiding it :)